# find the "string length" of an int

Tags: c

basically I want to return the number of digits in the int -> values like this:

```
(int)1 => 1
(int)123 => 3
(int)12345678 => 8
```

I know nothing about C, so please bear with me. I know objective c, but I use ints and floats instead of NSNumbers. I realise I could convert the ints into objective c objects, but this seems faffy, and if I can do it with C I'll know it for the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use

```
int d = (value == 0 ? 1 : (int)(log10(value)+1));
```

Note that this doesnt work for negative numbers, you'll have to use

```
int d = (value == 0 ? 1 : ((int)(log10(fabs(value))+1) + (value < 0 ? 1 : 0)));
```

which adds 1 for the minus sign, if `value` is negative.

Comment: (value < 0 ? 1 : 0) is equivalent to just (value < 0)

Comment: @Vovanium: Yes, but imho more readable. Implicit bool -> int conversions make me uneasy.

Comment: @Christopher: Result of < operator is int, not bool (in C). Readability? C programmer should understand this behavior so such syntactic noise doesn't add readability. Futhermore, this behavior is going to make idioms, like x += a>N; meaning "count a's greater than N".

Answer (score 13):

Probably much faster than using log or int-to-string conversion and without using any library functions is this:

```
int nDigits(int i)
{
  if (i < 0) i = -i;
  if (i <         10) return 1;
  if (i <        100) return 2;
  if (i <       1000) return 3;
  if (i <      10000) return 4;
  if (i <     100000) return 5;
  if (i <    1000000) return 6;      
  if (i <   10000000) return 7;
  if (i <  100000000) return 8;
  if (i < 1000000000) return 9;
  return 10;
}
```

**EDIT** after Jeff Yates concerns:

For those who worry about int sizes different from 32-bits
(similar to pmg's solution but still faster because multiplication is faster than division :-)

```
#include <limits.h>

#define PO10_LIMIT (INT_MAX/10)


int nDigits(int i)
{
  int n,po10;

  if (i < 0) i = -i;
  n=1;
  po10=10;
  while(i>=po10)
  {
    n++;
    if (po10 > PO10_LIMIT) break;
    po10*=10;
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: This is only good if `int` is a 32-bit value. As the size of `int` is platform dependent in C and C++, I wouldn't rely on this.

Comment: @Jeff Yates: I know! If this, however, is really a problem just add/remove some if instructions. And if you really need a solution that works on different platforms you can work with #if testing for the size of the particular int type or use pmg's solution (which still can be optimized).

Comment: Would it not be better to "else if" instead of "if" for the cascading tests option?

Comment: @Wade: depends on what you mean by "better". It would not improve performance because there are "return"s inside the "if" branches. I.e. all following "if"s won't be executed as soon as one "if" condition is true. (Though some people think it is bad to have more than one "return" in a function; I don't belong to those people)

Comment: @Curd, of course, you are correct.  I was thinking in terms of my own implementation for an unsigned short value that was not its own function, so an assignment instead of a return, and that's why this version appeared to be missing the 'else'.

Comment: This doesn't account for the 'negative sign' on negative numbers. -1 should have length 2.

Comment: @SmokingRope: yes, right. The functions return only the number of *digits*. So if you want to count also the '-' sign the `if (i < 0)`branch could do a recursive call `return 1 + nDigits(-i);` or (in the 2nd function) it could initialize `n` to 2.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option

```
int nDigits(unsigned i) {
    int n = 1;
    while (i > 9) {
        n++;
        i /= 10;
    }
    return n;
}
```

This is faster than using `log10`, but slower than Curd's option with the cascading tests. However it doesn't assume `int`s are 32 bits :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use logarithms base 10:

```
int length = (int)floor(log10((float)number)) + 1; // works for >0
```

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution, especially if you want to know the length for purposes of printing with `printf()` variants is:

```
snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", myint);
```

The return value should tell you the length of the string that would be printed.

Comment: @pst: Why'd you snip off the `\0` part?

Comment: The NUL is not included in the string length just by being a C string. (It was just the phrasing used.)

Answer (score 1):

If your integer value (e.g. `12345678u`) is a compile-time constant, you can let the compiler determine the length for you:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr unsigned int_decimal_digits(T value)
{
    return (    value / 10
                    ?   int_decimal_digits<T>(value/10) + 1
                    :   1 );
}
```

Usage:

```
unsigned n = int_decimal_digits(1234); 
// n = 4

#include <limits.h>
unsigned m = int_decimal_digits(ULLONG_MAX);
// m = maximum length of a "long long unsigned" on your platform
```

This way, the compiler will compute the number of decimal places automatically, and fill in the value as a constant. It should be the fastest possible solution, because there is no run-time computation involved and integer constants are usually put into the instruction opcodes. (This means that they travel by instruction pipeline, not by data memory/cache.) However, this requires a compiler that supports C++11.