# Get number of digits in an unsigned long integer c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, numbers

I'm trying to determine the number of digits in a c# ulong number, i'm trying to do so using some math logic rather than using ToString().Length. I have not benchmarked the 2 approaches but have seen other posts about using System.Math.Floor(System.Math.Log10(number)) + 1 to determine the number of digits.
Seems to work fine until i transition from 999999999999997 to 999999999999998 at which point, it i start getting an incorrect count.

Has anyone encountered this issue before ?

I have seen similar posts with a Java emphasis @ [Why log(1000)/log(10) isn't the same as log10(1000)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497400/why-log1000-log10-isnt-the-same-as-log101000) and also a post @ [How to get the separate digits of an int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389264/how-to-get-the-separate-digits-of-an-int-number) which indicates how i could possibly achieve the same using the % operator but with a lot more code

Here is the code i used to simulate this

```
Action<ulong> displayInfo = number => 
 Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20} {3,-20} {4,-20}", 
  number, 
  number.ToString().Length, 
  System.Math.Log10(number), 
  System.Math.Floor(System.Math.Log10(number)),
  System.Math.Floor(System.Math.Log10(number)) + 1);

Array.ForEach(new ulong[] {
 9U,
 99U,
 999U,
 9999U,
 99999U,
 999999U,
 9999999U,
 99999999U,
 999999999U,
 9999999999U,
 99999999999U,
 999999999999U,
 9999999999999U,
 99999999999999U,
 999999999999999U,
 9999999999999999U,
 99999999999999999U,
 999999999999999999U,
 9999999999999999999U}, displayInfo);

Array.ForEach(new ulong[] {
 1U,
 19U,
 199U,
 1999U,
 19999U,
 199999U,
 1999999U,
 19999999U,
 199999999U,
 1999999999U,
 19999999999U,
 199999999999U,
 1999999999999U,
 19999999999999U,
 199999999999999U,
 1999999999999999U,
 19999999999999999U,
 199999999999999999U,
 1999999999999999999U
}, displayInfo);
```

Thanks in advance

Pat

Comment: You don’t need the `%` operator, integer division is enough. And the “lot more code” is a single-statement loop. Not all that much code.

Comment: Is ToString().Length really that expensive of a call? Maybe its a hair slower but it will be accurate for any value. To me, accuracy is more desirable than efficiency.

Comment: It makes sense that you start getting incorrect results when using the `Log10` function, because that function uses the `double` type, which cannot represent very large integers exactly (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: I agree, I don't see anything particularly wrong with using `ToString().Length`. Also, you can change your `Action` to a regular method, as long as the signature is correct.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143000/find-the-string-length-of-an-int -- see the "cascading if" version if you want "speed" (can be broken into parts with a few divide similar to the iterative method). Otherwise might a well just `ToString` here. The `if` can be moved into a fast-break iteration of a List.

Comment: If you decide to use ToString please make sure to specify correct (invariant) culture - there are cultures where integers have separators in them like 100,000, as result ToString().Length will be wrong in such cultures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

log10 is going to involve floating point conversion - hence the rounding error. The error is pretty small for a double, but is a big deal for an exact integer!

Excluding the .ToString() method and a floating point method, then yes I think you are going to have to use an iterative method but I would use an integer divide rather than a modulo.

Integer divide by 10. Is the result>0? If so iterate around. If not, stop.
The number of digits is the number of iterations required.

Eg. 5 -> 0;  1 iteration = 1 digit.

1234 -> 123 -> 12 -> 1 -> 0;  4 iterations = 4 digits.

Comment: Just a tease: A slight modification of this approach can actually be done with only *integer multiply* and compares. Looking at the lookup-table in my reply should shed some insight (no lookup-table required for the previous sentence).

Comment: Sure, do it in reverse. And this might be preferable if the multiply op is faster.

Comment: It *is* faster. Question is if it's perceivable ;-) I just felt like leaving the comment because this struck me the other night -- after finishing my post -- and realized I've never seen it suggested as a solution for this problem before (that could mean one of several things...).

Answer (score 6):

I would use `ToString().Length` unless you know this is going to be called millions of times.

"premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx):

> By default, a Double value contains 15
>   decimal digits of precision, although
>   a maximum of 17 digits is maintained
>   internally.

I suspect that you're running into precision limits.  Your value of 999,999,999,999,998 probably is at the limit of precision.  And since the `ulong` has to be converted to `double` before calling `Math.Log10`, you see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have posted *why* this happens.

Here is an example of a fairly quick way to determine the "length" of an integer (some cases excluded). This by itself is not very interesting -- but I include it here because using this method *in conjunction with Log10* can get the accuracy "perfect" for the entire range of an unsigned long without requiring a second log invocation.

```
// the lookup would only be generated once
// and could be a hard-coded array literal
ulong[] lookup = Enumerable.Range(0, 20)
    .Select((n) => (ulong)Math.Pow(10, n)).ToArray();
ulong x = 999;
int i = 0;
for (; i < lookup.Length; i++) {
    if (lookup[i] > x) {
        break;
    }
}
// i is length of x "in a base-10 string"
// does not work with "0" or negative numbers
```

This lookup-table approach can be easily converted to any base. *This method should be faster than the iterative divide-by-base approach* but profiling is left as an exercise to the reader. (A direct if-then branch broken into "groups" is likely quicker yet, but that's way too much repetitive typing for my tastes.)

Happy coding.

Comment: Making lookup table static and using binary search instead of direct iteration may speed up this solution a bit more. If need to be seed up even more rolling out binary search into series of if statements may be the fastest.