# Is there a better way to find length of any String or a Number?

Tags: c

Here is one way but the problem with it is unnecessary usage of output screen.

```
lenth=printf("%d",num);// or lenth=printf("%s",str);
```

How could i find length without having output from printf?

Comment: Use `strlen` function for string.

Comment: Do you mean, to find a length of decimal number representation?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one...

Comment: For a number or a string? Because they aren't the same internally ...

Comment: i want to reduce my execution time for online submission so dosent matter but basically C

Comment: @AntonH more for a number

Comment: @Abhishek Use modulus and count the digits for a number (+1 for sign).

Comment: You probably just want to divide by 10 repeatedly until you get zero, not counting an initial zero. If you really must go the printf route, there's sprintf to print to a buffer - but don't do that.

Comment: Use a raw literal operator template and return sizeof...(cs) where cs is a char parameter pack.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it takes more time as the size of a number increases....and less efficient than that given above.....

Comment: @0x499602D2 please elaborate

Comment: @Abhishek Then use something like `std::to_string(num).size();`

Comment: just use `snprintf` with big enough buffer

Comment: Oh come on, it's perfectly clear what he's asking.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384956/is-there-a-file-pointer-file-that-points-to-nothing

Comment: @QuestionC not really

Comment: `strlen("string")` works for a string in C. In C++ you can use `std::string str = "hello";`. In terms of int, I'll direct you here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9655202/2986033

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::to_string(num).size();` should be an answer. It's informative and will serve to educate those coming after who may have the same question.

Comment: @RichardHodges Unfortunately the OP seems quite resistant to decide for [tag:c] or [tag:c++], also the question's [on hold] for now. No question improvement, no answer.

Comment: _@Abhishek_ As you have decided for [tag:c] finally you should use something like @Slava suggested along with `stren()`.

Comment: @Abhishek Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068397/finding-the-length-of-an-integer-in-c or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143000/find-the-string-length-of-an-int

Comment: @QuestionC It takes a certain amount and sort of intelligence to look at the question and infer what is (obviously) being asked. Empirical evidence suggests that most people lack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) with an *empty* buffer (i.e. pass a null pointer), which will return the number of characters that would have been written into the buffer if there was enough space in it:

```
int length = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", num);
```

This way, you don't need to use an actual buffer and it won't print on `stdout` like `printf()` does.